# A simple integral on a one-dimensional manifold

Tags: integration, analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

My aim is to compute an integral over a semicircle using the notion of integration on manifolds only.

For this purpose, define a one-dimensional $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$-manifold $M := \mathbb{S}^{1}-\{(1, 0) \}$ and a coordinate system $(M, \psi)$ on it, with $M \ni (x, y)  \overset{\psi}{\mapsto} \frac{y}{1-x} \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, let $\sigma$ be a differentiable singular $1$-simplex in $M$ defined as follows: $[0, 1] \ni t \overset{\sigma}{\mapsto} (-\sin(\pi t), \cos(\pi t))\in M$. Obviously, it's just a semicircle parametrized anti-clockwise starting from the point $(0, 1)$ up to the point $(0, -1)$.

For the differential form $\omega = 2\; d\psi$, I want to compute the value of $\int_{\sigma} \omega$. By the definition, $\int_{\sigma} \omega = \int_{[0, 1]} \delta \sigma(\omega)$, where $\delta\sigma$ denotes the pull-back of $\sigma$, i.e. ${\delta\sigma}_{m} : T^{*}_{\sigma(m)}M \rightarrow T^{*}_{m}\mathbb{R}$ and $\delta\sigma(\omega)(w) = \omega(d\sigma(w))$, $w \in T_{m}\mathbb{R}$.

And so, 
\begin{align*}
d\sigma(\frac{d}{d t}\Bigr|_{\substack{m}}) =& \frac{d\sigma}{d t}\Bigr|_{\substack{m}}\;\; \frac{\partial}{\partial \psi}\Bigr|_{\substack{\sigma(m)}} \\
=& \big(-\pi\cos(\pi m), -\pi\sin(\pi m)\big)\;\;\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi}\Bigr|_{\substack{\sigma(m)}}.
\end{align*}

But now, how do I apply this result to $\omega$?

Comment: This pullback notation of Warner's is truly atrocious. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $d\psi$ is the restriction to $M$ of the $1$-form $\eta=\dfrac{(1-x)dy+y\,dx}{(1-x)^2}$ on $\Bbb R^2-\{x=0\}$. Now pull back by $\sigma$:
$$\sigma^*\eta = \frac{(1+\sin\pi t)(-\pi\sin\pi t)+(\cos\pi t)(-\pi \cos\pi t)}{(1+\sin\pi t)^2}dt = -\pi \frac{dt}{1+\sin\pi t}.$$
This is sort of yucky, but you can integrate on $[0,1]$ by the usual calculus trick of multiplying and dividing by $1-\sin\pi t$.

Comment: The problem is that integrating $\sigma^{*}\eta$ on $[0, 1]$ gives $2$, not $2\pi$, as it should...

Comment: Actually, it gives $-2$, but it should not give $2\pi$. This is *not* the usual $d\theta$ (up to scalar multiple) on the circle. You can see this directly by drawing a little picture. If $\alpha$ is the angle subtended by the $x$-axis and the ray from $(1,0)$ to $(x,y)$, then $\psi(x,y)=\frac y{1-x} = \tan\alpha$, so $d\psi = d(\tan\alpha)$, *not* $d\alpha$. Note, moreover, that the usual polar coordinate $\theta$ is related to $\alpha$ by  $\theta = \pi - 2\alpha$, so $d\theta = -2 d\alpha$.